# SQL or HANA - How to create separate columns for each union statement in one report

Tags: sql, pivot, hana

I have a HANA query that is summarizing sales data by year, by customer.

```
SELECT YEAR(T0."DocDate"), T0."CardName"  "Customer", SUM(T0."DocTotal")  "Sales Amt"
FROM ORDR T0 GROUP BY YEAR(T0."DocDate"), T0."CardName"
```

It looks like this:

[image: Current query results]

What I am trying to figure out is, how to get the summaries by year to be displayed horizontally.

[image: Something like this]

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic variant of **pivoting** a result set, that is swapping the axis.
SAP HANA SQL does currently (up to HANA 2 SP01) not provide a PIVOT/UNPIVOT command, which means, that the effect has to be modelled manually.

In SQL a common pattern for this looks like this:

```
with base (SELECT YEAR(T0."DocDate") "Year"
                , T0."CardName"  "Customer"
                , SUM(T0."DocTotal")  "Sales Amt"
           FROM 
               ORDR T0 
          GROUP BY YEAR(T0."DocDate"), T0."CardName"),

 SELECT "Customer", SUM("2014") as "2014", 0 as SUM("2015") as "2015"
 FROM
    (SELECT "Customer", "Sales Amt" as "2014", 0 as "2015"
    FROM base
    WHERE "Year" = 2014
  UNION ALL
   SELECT "Customer", 0 as "2014, "Sales Amt" as "2015"
    FROM base
    WHERE "Year" = 2015)
 GROUP BY "Customer";
```

The "base" view that we build with the common table expression in the first part of the query produces the aggregated data per year.
The `UNION ALL` creates a output table `"Customer"`, `"2014"`, `"2015"` and filters on the relevant year. For the other year, a constant `0` value is produced.
Finally, this result set gets combined with `SUM()` aggregates in the outer query.

Obviously this is a very static approach since both the filter conditions and the column labels are hard coded in the query. This is one reason for having this sort of transformation in the reporting tool instead of the database.

One option to make this a bit more dynamic would be to create a table function that accepts the filter conditions as parameters and returns columns named like `"Year_base"`, `"Year+1"`, `"Year+2"`, ... that way the output structure would always stay fixed and the receiving application would only have to deal with labelling the "Year"-columns correctly.

A similar approach like the one described above can also be achieved with graphical calculation views. The base table would be fed into multiple projections with restricted key figures (effectively filters that decide which records are considered for the aggregation) and then merged together via `UNION` and `AGGREGATION`. For that, there are plenty of examples available online.

Answer (score 0):

Use Crosstabs in crystal report. This is the best solution pivot the rows to column, Use the same query and specify the year in the column field in the crosstab